# Do i need to always connect to internet when creating or working on react app?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npx

I am starting to learn a framework i was just curious if i need to have internet connection in working with `create-react-app`

Comment: Why don't you try ?

Comment: Because i have limited slow and limited internet connection, i am choosing a framework which i can work offline with,

Comment: Why don't you try offline and see if it works ?

Comment: You just need internet to download the node_modules, then you can use it and run the application offline

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To create the react project, you will need internet connection so npx would download all the dependencies for `create-react-app`.

But as soon as your project is configured (and if you won't do any backend/API request) you'll no longer need internet connection, your project will be running on localhost.