# I am facing the issue below while creating a React app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npx

```
PS F:\Programming Tutorials Videos\R Practice> npx create-react-app custom-hook
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\GALAXY COMPUTERS\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-06T17_33_28_552Z-debug-0.logtype here
```

I have installed node.js latest version but problem persist And with internet Connection I created React App Why is that, when I am not Connected to Internet it doesn't create React App

Comment: _"Why is that, when I am not Connected to Internet it doesn't create React App"_ - Because the files are being downloaded, and without an active connection it cannot download them. You can use a local npm registry, but that still requires an initial internet connection.

Comment: Are you using a proxy or VPN? Have you tried to ping `https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app` or use the URL on the browser to see if you can reach it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do i need to always connect to internet when creating or working on react app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60893434/do-i-need-to-always-connect-to-internet-when-creating-or-working-on-react-app)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `create-react-app` with `npx` command it connect to your network and create new project that need to install dependencies on which your project depend on like `react` , `react-dom` etc hence it required network connection.

Comment: Even you have installed nodejs but to get other required packages it connect to network and fetch packages from npm

Comment: could you please tell me how to create-react-app without internet connection although I have installed all node.js and other necessary tools

Comment: You can use pnpm to reuse the installed packages from your local but first time it still required network connection to cache packages.